# Visual Studio project file specify multiple import

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wix, windows-installer

I have a C# project. I want to build an exe or an MSI, depending on the configuration.

The MSI is defined as

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">MSI</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
  <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
  <ProjectGuid>{DCB76E90-6364-4DFB-B568-3680EE4F9C80}</ProjectGuid>
  <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  <OutputName>Project1</OutputName>
  <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
  <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
  <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'MSI|x86' ">
  <OutputPath>bin\MSI2\</OutputPath>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="MyWxs.wxs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The problem is that when I try to have both

```
<Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
```

and

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Error

```
A problem occurred while trying to set the "TargetType" parameter for the IDE's in-process compiler.
Invalid target type "package" for /target: must specify 'exe', 'winexe', 'library', or 'module'.
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot import both of those targets into a single project. They both expect to be able to handle the `Compile` items (with completely different tools, namely: `candle.exe` and `csc.exe`). You need separate projects. Typically, `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` go in a .csproj and `Wix.targets` go in a .wixproj.

Comment: The big picture: I have four projects, three of which build an executable. I need an MSI for each one. Does this mean I need to add three projects, each one essentially empty other than the .wixproj?

Comment: Typically you have a .wixproj per .msi just like you have a project per executable. You can do more advanced tricks with your projects to minimize the number of projects if you want. You can see us doing this with the Visual Studio integration in the WiX toolset at src\Setup\VotiveMsi in wix38 branch.